# How can you calculate the integral $\int_{-1}^1\frac{\cos x}{e^{1/x}+1}\;dx$?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

How can you calculate the following integral

$$
\int_{-1}^1\frac{\cos x}{e^{1/x}+1}\;dx=\;?
$$

---

First of all, there is no problem at the singularity $x=0$:
$$
\lim_{x\to 0+}\frac{\cos x}{e^{1/x}+1}=0, \quad \lim_{x\to 0-}\frac{\cos x}{e^{1/x}+1}=1\;.
$$

[image]

The integral *per se* is not very appealing: who cares what the value is? But the *methods* to handle it may be very interesting. I was very surprised when I first saw one trick (see my [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3650280/765539) below) to solve this problem; it turns out that that trick is connected to Fourier analysis in some sense.

I look forward to seeing alternative approaches if any.

Answer (score 6):

Any real-valued function $f:\mathbf{R}\to\mathbf{R}$ can be written as a sum $f = f_o+f_e$ where $f_o$ is an odd function: $f_o(-x)=-f_o(x)$ and $f_e$ is even: $f_e(-x)=f_e(x)$. Such decomposition is a simple prototype of the [Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform). <sup>1</sup> The proof is simple:
$$
f_o(x) := \frac{f(x)-f(-x)}{2},\quad f_e(x) := \frac{f(x)+f(-x)}{2}\;.
$$

Now, if one denotes the integrand as $\displaystyle f(x) = \frac{\cos(x)}{e^{1/x}+1}$ and decomposes it as above, then one immediately has
$$
\int_{-1}^1f(x)\;dx = \int_{-1}^1f_e(x)\;dx\tag{1}
$$
because the integral of any odd functions on a symmetric interval is zero. So the problem reduces to (1). But
$$
2f_e(x) = \frac{\cos(x)}{e^{1/x}+1}+\frac{\cos(x)}{e^{-1/x}+1} 
= \cos(x)\cdot \frac{e^{-1/x}+1+e^{1/x}+1}{2+e^{1/x}+e^{-1/x}}=\cos(x)\tag{2}
$$

One can now easily go on with (2) to find the answer.<sup>2</sup>

---

Notes.

1. See [this](https://www.math.ucla.edu/~tao/preprints/fourier.pdf) excellent PCM ([The Princeton Companion to Mathematics](https://press.princeton.edu/books/hardcover/9780691118802/the-princeton-companion-to-mathematics)) article on the Fourier transform by Terence Tao. See also Section 5 of [this set of lecture notes](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/04/06/the-fourier-transform/) by Tao on how the even and odd decomposition relates to the Fourier transform.
2. This method is also presented in Nahin's *Inside Interesting Integrals*.

Comment: Nahin's entire book is a must-read, by the way.

Answer (score 6):

Note

$$
\int_{-1}^1\frac{\cos x}{e^{1/x}+1}\;dx
= \int_{-1}^0\frac{\cos x}{e^{1/x}+1}\;dx +\int_{0}^1\frac{\cos x}{e^{1/x}+1}\;dx \\
\overset{x=-t} = \int_{0}^1\frac{\cos t}{e^{-1/t}+1}\;dt +\int_{0}^1\frac{\cos x}{e^{1/x}+1}\;dx \\
= \int_{0}^1\cos t \left(\frac{1}{e^{-1/t}+1}+\frac{1}{e^{1/t}+1}\right)\;dt \\
\hspace{-2cm}= \int_{0}^1\cos t dt= \sin (1)
$$